# How to connect this monitor to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: screen

So I disassembled an old laptop and removed its screen.

[image]

In the back of the screen, there's a circuit board with this cable

[image]

which eventually leads into the board shown below the screen (along with 2 pink & white cables, which I assume are for power), where the output is this cable

[image]

What are the names of these components (the type of cables), and how can I use this monitor in my RaspberryPi?

My idea was to use a simple converter from the Pi DSI output into the board in the back of the screen, and plug the 2 pink/white cables into the Pi's power pins, but I doubt it could be this simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this [video](https://youtu.be/6SOXMDb4cjI).

On the back of your screen there should be a model number - you'll just need to find the right controller for that screen's model number. You should be able to order it from eBay and that will become the adapter to an HDMI cable for your Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering specific details, I followed the answer given by Quintin Balsdon and order this [item](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/VGA-LCD-Controller-Board-Module-Inverter-Lvds-Cable-for-B154EW01-LP154W01-LTN154X3-LTN154AT07-1280x800-1ch-6bit/32821910700.html), a VGA LCD Controller Board. I used an old power cable with similar power values, a VGA cable to connect the controller to a computer and voilá.